# Observable, unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, unsubscribe

I have a dialog that opens and contains a component... in the component I do a subscription. When closing I want to unsubscribe..

```
private deviceObserver: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.XSmall]);

this.deviceObserver.subscribe(result => {
  if (result.matches) {
    this.deviceType = 'mobile';
  } else {
    this.deviceType = 'desktop';
  }
});

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.deviceObserver.unsubscribe();
}
```

That gives me this error:

Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?

Comment: first you have to subscribe, assign it to a variable and then you can unsubscribe a subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason doing the unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy broke the app... This is how I solved it:

```
private deviceObserver: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.XSmall]);
private breakpointObserverSubscription: Subscription;


// in ngOnInit()
this.breakpointObserverSubscription = this.deviceObserver.subscribe(result => {
  if (result.matches) {
    this.deviceType = 'mobile';
  } else {
    this.deviceType = 'desktop';
  }
});

public closeSearch() {
 this.onClose.apply();
 this.breakpointObserverSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only use `unsubscribe` on a `Subscription`. You are trying to use it on a `Observable`.

If you use the observable inside your component using the `async` pipe, then you do not need to unsubscribe. This is automatically done by the framework.

If however you use it inside your `component.ts`, then one way is to do it like this. There are also other options, using the `takeUntil` pipe for instance:

```
private deviceObserver: Observable<BreakpointState> = 
                        this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.XSmall]);

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.deviceObserver.subscribe(result => {
    if (result.matches) {
      this.deviceType = 'mobile';
    } else {
      this.deviceType = 'desktop';
    }
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but that broke features.. did some more digging and if I do this in the ngOnDestroy it breaks.. so I moved the unsubscribe to the closeDialog method and that worked fine! :)

Comment: that seems unlikely. Your code is using `unsubscribe` on an observable, you should not do that :) but safe a reference to the subscription (or use takeUntil)

Comment: See my updated question (was missing code haha).. also posted the working code as an answer. I think there is something wrong when I open the cdk's OverlayRef and attaching the component to a ComponentPortal

Comment: The code in your answer uses the subscription reference, the code in your question does not. I see no reason why using the subscription reference wouldn't work in ngOnDestroy

Comment: Well me neither but the document.addEventListener('keydown'... code works only on first keydown when I add the ngOnDestroy (with or without the subscribe/unsubscribe

Comment: why would you not use `(keydown)`? The reason it only works once, is probably because you are attaching it in some ngOnInit hook, and the element on which you attach it, gets destroyed and rebuild after every angular change detection check.. If it is inside an `*ngFor`, you should use the `trackBy` functionality

Comment: not sure what you mean.. (this is not keydown in a component but in a service)